# How to define relative / cross-platform screenshot paths in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, cross-platform, build-automation, screenshot, selenium-ide

As part of automated Selenium tests, I like to take screenshots of different UI views, store them in some directory, and later have them published by the CI tool ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) in our case) for the latest successful build.

[image]

In an HTML Selenium test case, capturing a screenshot looks something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>captureEntirePageScreenshot</td>
    <td>/tmp/screenshot-reportpage-1.png</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

So far, I've used paths like `/tmp/` as the tests are run on a Unix/Linux box, and I develop on Linux too.

Now, I run into a problem when a **Windows-using colleague needs to run the same tests locally** with Selenium IDE. An absolute Windows path like `C:\screenshot-1.png` would work on his machine, but not on the build server, of course.

We've tried using a simple relative path, e.g. `screenshot-1.png` or `./screenshot-1.png`, but that fails with a nasty error message in Selenium IDE:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: message -> Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 
(NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath], QueryInterface -> function 
QueryInterface() { [native code] }, result -> 2152857601, name -> NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH,  
filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 3030,    
columnNumber -> 0, location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js
:: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 3030, inner -> null, data -> null, initialize -> function initialize() { [native code] }
```

Question is, **is it possible to specify a relative path** here? Is there *any* way to get this working in both environments without having to modify the test HTML files?

Answer (score 2):

Guess I am late to the party, anyway was working with Selenium IDE 2.9.1 through a project and came across this problem. The correct preference key is actually "testCaseDirectory". They've probably changed it.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Preferences.getString("testCaseDirectory")</td>
    <td>testSuiteFolder</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>captureEntirePageScreenshot</td>
    <td>${testSuiteFolder}/screenshots/screenshot-reportpage-1.png</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the folder relative to the Test Suite:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Preferences.getString(TestSuite.TEST_SUITE_DIRECTORY_PREF);</td>
    <td>testSuiteFolder</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>captureEntirePageScreenshot</td>
    <td>${testSuiteFolder}/screenshots/screenshot-reportpage-1.png</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making the path a variable that gets set on launch using data-driven testing?

http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/selenium-resources-for-newbs-data-driven-testing-with-ide-xml/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this addon

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stored-variables-viewer-seleni/